# Determining index each group duplicate values in an array in Python with the fastest way

Tags: python, performance, numpy, duplicates

I want to find an index of each group duplicate value like this:

```
s = [2,6,2,88,6,...]
```

The results must return the index from `original s`: `[[0,2],[1,4],..]` or the result can show another way.

I find many solutions so I find the fastest way to get duplicate group:

```
s = np.sort(a, axis=None)
s[:-1][s[1:] == s[:-1]]
```

But after sort I got wrong index from `original s`.

In my case, I have ~ 200mil value on the list and I want to find the fastest way to do that. I use an array to store value because I want to use GPU to make it faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hash structures like `dict` helps.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

a=np.array([2,4,2,88,15,4])
table=defaultdict(list)
for ind,num in enumerate(a):
    table[num]+=[ind]
```

Outputs:

```
{2: [0, 2], 4: [1, 5], 88: [3], 15: [4]}
```

If you want to show duplicated elements in the order from small to large:

```py
for k,v in sorted(table.items()):
    if len(v)>1:
        print(k,":",v)
```

Outputs:

```
2 : [0, 2]
4 : [1, 5]
```

The speed is determined by how many different values in the number list.

Comment: hi @Autumnii, I tested your solution at ~20mil data and need at 34 seconds. It seems good, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this meets your performance requirements (here, `s` is your input array):

```
counts       = np.bincount(s)
cum_counts   = np.add.accumulate(counts)
sorted_inds  = np.argsort(s)

result       = np.split(sorted_inds, cum_counts[:-1])
```

**Notes:**

1. The `result` would be a list of arrays.
2. Each of these arrays would contain indices of a repeated value in `s`. Eg, if the value `13` is repeated `7` times in `s`, there would be an array with `7` indices among the arrays of `result`
3. If you want to ignore singleton values of `s` (values that occur only once in `s`), you can pass `minlength=2` to `np.bincount()`

Answer (score 0):

(This is a variation of my other answer. Here, instead of splitting the large array `sorted_inds`, we take slices from it, so it's likely to have a different kind of performance characteristic)

If `s` is the input array:

```
counts       = np.bincount(s)
cum_counts   = np.add.accumulate(counts)
sorted_inds  = np.argsort(s)

result = [sorted_inds[:cum_counts[0]]] + [sorted_inds[cum_counts[i]:cum_counts[i+1]] for i in range(cum_counts.size-1)]
```

Comment: hi @fountainhead, I have an error `Unable to allocate 33.3 PiB for an array with shape (4688145146881523,) and data type int64`. My python version is 3.7.8 and 64-bit. I tried to fix the error but can not. Did u have any ideas?

Comment: @ToanNguyenPhuoc -- It looks like a memory constraint. On which line did it occur? The `argsort()` ?

Comment: At line `np.bincount(s)`

Comment: What is the size of the input array?

Comment: The size of the input array is 20 million

Comment: I am new to the situation (insufficient memory), so even if there's a quick solution (involving some settings), I wouldn't know. However, I can try to explore alternative solutions (that avoid using `np.bincount()`, in the hope that the alternative solutions will not run into a memory constraint situation. Could you pls comment out all lines and run only the line that has `argsort()`, and let me know whether that line can run successfully, or is that also running into memory crunch?

Comment: the line that has `sorted_inds  = np.argsort(datas)` can run successfully

Comment: You could try replacing `counts       = np.bincount(s)` with `_,counts = np.unique(s, return_counts=True)`. This is another way of getting `counts`. Actually, this doesn't seem like such a good idea, since `np.unique()` does some other things also, which we are not interested in. Overall, I don't seem to have a good,, working solution for your posted problem ! The other answer which iteratively builds a dictionary seems to be the best bet, for now.